# Raspberry pi3 Failed to connect to device

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

To get started with Raspberry pi3 I try to get the https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/iot/samples/helloworld sample to work, but I can't deploy to my device. I get the following error:
***DEP6957 : Failed to connect to device  using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. 0x8007274C: The network event being waited on triggered an error.***

My PC has Windows 10 Version 1607 (Build1493.693)
The OS Version of my device is OS Version: 10.0.14393.693
I updated the SDK to Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

I can connect to my device with the Windows Device Portal
What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: I disconnected the device from ethernet and used the Wifi connection. There I could connect and deploy. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

When connecting through wifi Visual Studio should find your Pi without issue, thus it can use it's device name. When connected though an Ethernet cable, for some reason VS isn't able to find the pi which is why you will need to use an IP address.

Why visual studio doesn't automatically find your Pi? I don't know. I have had the same problem, but as far as I know this doesn't happen to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that I have found the answer.
The connection fails, when using the device name.
When using the IP-Address instead, I can connect and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.. I discovered that I entered the ip address of my Raspberry Pi 3 to Visual Studio with "http://" prefix, that is:

http://169.254.35.56

I just removed the prefix so that the ip address will be as:

169.254.35.56

and the problem solved.

[enter your own ip address]